# Getting GridViewRow data into DataRow in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Below is a loop I am trying to use to get the values from a GridViewRow into a DataRow object (using the godforsaken language of Visual Basic). However, on this line:

```
                dr(i) = r.Cells(i).Text
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
the value of type string cannot be converted to system.data.datarow
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

```
        Dim rows As New List(Of GridViewRow)()

        For Each item As GridViewRow In grdExpProd.Rows
            rows.Add(item)
        Next

        Dim value As Integer = rows.Count

        Dim dt As New DataTable()


        For index As Integer = value - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim dr As DataRow()
            Dim r As GridViewRow = rows(index)

            For i As Integer = 0 To r.Cells.Count - 1
                dr(i) = r.Cells(i).Text
            Next

            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to be adding your text to the [DataRows Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which will allow you access to the individual cells of the DataRow. You are also going to need to add the columns that exist in your GridRowView to your new `DataTable`.

```
For i = 1 To rows(0).Cells.Count
    dt.Columns.Add("Header" & i)
Next

For index As Integer = value - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    Dim r As GridViewRow = rows(index)

    For i As Integer = 0 To r.Cells.Count 
        dr.Item(i) = r.Cells(i).Text
    Next

    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next
```

Comment: The Item property should be treated as an indexer, so you wouldn't need to refer to it by name; dr(i) should be sufficient.

Comment: @ekolis you are right, I just did that to clarify that it was analogous to the GridViewRow's Columns.

Answer (score 0):

You accidentally created dr as an array of DataRow objects, not as a single DataRow object. Try replacing

```
Dim dr As DataRow()
```

with

```
Dim dr As New DataRow()
```

Comment: Oops. However, this brings up a new error, saying that dr  "is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected.Friend'

Comment: Hmm. No idea why your data row variable would be protected friend when you just declared it right there as a local variable. Or are you talking about the constructor? Another poster suggested using dt.NewRow(); perhaps that's how you're actually supposed to create a data row?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Dim dr As DataRow()
```

with

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
```

Also, as another poster pointed out, you need to create columns in your data table before attempting to add rows to it.

Comment: This allows the code to compile, however this line: dr(i) = r.Cells(i).Text throws an error during the first iteration of the loop. It cannot find the column at index 0 for dr. Any ideas on how to get around this? Looks like this is the way to go (I hope)

Comment: @NealR  Ah, I see, your table doesn't have any columns!  Therefore, the row has no items.  You need to create and add DataColumn objects to the DataTable Columns collection before you attempt to create new rows.